# How do I create an if statement that sets an individual variable equal to at least one of my array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a line of code that is supposed to act as a check for if the user inputs a value that isn't within my array.

I made an array with all valid inputs and then made and if statement that checks this.

```
var productCode = ["LT","ST","DC","LC","PR","SP"];

var productChosen = prompt("Choose a product code, LT, ST, DC, LC, PR, or SP");

if ( productChosen === productCode) {

etc..
}

else {

alert("Please input a valid product code");
}
```

It always goes to the else statement.

Comment: `productCode.includes(productChosen)`. might want to conVerT CasE for users...

Comment: please post your full code

Answer (score 1):

The `productChosen` is a string. The `productCode` is an array.  These types can never be equal.  What you are looking for is [`includes()`](https://appdividend.com/2019/03/14/javascript-array-includes-example-array-prototype-includes-tutorial/#targetText=The%20includes()%20method%20determines,the%20array%20contains%20a%20substring.) to check if the string is included in the array.

```
if(productCode.includes(productChosen)) { ... }
```